# how to add currency pattern to input element while typing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, currency-formatting

```
<input type="text" id="currency" />
```

> onChange and onblur Not works as typing

so i want while (as soon as ) i type it formats to me like

1000/000 or 100,000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function setFormat(id) {

  if (document.getElementById(id).value != "") {
    document.getElementById(id).value = parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value.replace(/\//g, ""))
      .toString()
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "/");
  }
}
```

```css
#currency {
  text-align: left;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="currency" oninput="setFormat('currency')" />
```

Comment: how to do this in angular ? Any idea ?